# Should I enable open_basedir?

Tags: php, security, open-basedir, php-ini

I read that open_basedir should be 'On' for better security. Is that true? Should I enable it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211612/what-is-the-use-of-open-basedir-in-php-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 1):

Why not to read this directive's explanation and decide for yourself?
It can add some security, as well as inconvenience. The choice is yours. 
If your site is already insecure, it won't help it much.